# How do I disable a standard/guest user's Aero effects from an administrator account in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, aero

I need to disable the Aero effects for a standard/guest user in Windows 7 (it should still be enabled for the administrator). I have an administrator account, but don't know how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: windows 7 pro / home ... ?

Comment: Hi Rovolter, I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise

Answer (score 0):

You should right click on desktop and click personalize.

[image]

Then you should set a basic theme which does not have Aero property.

[image]

You can also personalize the colors, wallpaper and screensaver on the same screen.

Comment: Thanks, NT, but as I said, I would like to disable the AERO of a guest account, but a guest account doesn't have any access to Personalize option.